# how to set same action / process to multiple buttons in java

Tags: java, javafx, actionlistener

I want to create the same actions on multiple buttons of my interface. Is it only feasible by creating seperate action listener methods and calling the method which does the actions or is there any other way? Is it possible by putting the buttons in a group and doing as:-

`groupButton.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
   public void handle(MouseEvent event){
     //some other method called
   }

   }`

Answer (score 2):

(You should really use `setOnAction(...)` to handle button presses, rather than `setOnMousePressed()`, but I'll answer the question as posed.)

Just create the handler and assign it to a variable:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        // handle event...
    }
};

groupButton.setOnMousePressed(handler);
someOtherButton.setOnMousePressed(handler);
```